# Python logging when the script is running

Tags: python, logging

I have a script that will be running 24/7 as a service and I'm currently using `logging` module to log into files.

The issue is, that I only get logs when my script stops, which isn't what I'm looking for because I need to check if the script is running correctly in real-time.

For example, let's say I have simple code like this:

```
while True:
    info_logger.info('This is an info message')
    time.sleep(10)
```

The info_logger is set up earlier, using

```
handler = logging.FileHandler('filepath')
info_logger = logging.getLogger('info_logger')
info_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
info_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

The logger is working perfectly fine when script ends, but I want to collect logs as the script is running. Is there a way to do it using logging? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to change the line `info_logger = logger.getLogger('info_logger')` to `info_logger = logging.getLogger('info_logger')`. When I ran the code on my machine with that change, it succesfully wrote to the file while the script was running.

Comment: Sorry, I made a spelling mistake in the question with `logger.getLogger('info_logger)`, in my script it's in the correct form as You corrected it. It does collect logs when the script is running, but I can't see them, because they are created when the script ends.

Comment: @DominikPiętak That's weird because for me the log is created as soon as the script starts. I can open the file and see the script logging the messages real-time.

Comment: When I add StreamHandler to sys.stdout, I can see them in real-time in the console, but the files are created or new lines are added when the script ends :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think it has to do with PyCharm not updating files in real-time.

When I've used 'Reload from Disk' on the file, it's up to date.

Comment: Is this the answer then? So when opening the file directly or doing `ls -l`, it shows you the last modified time recently, regardless of the script finishing or not? Then it's working fine?